# How to compare output of two different hosts in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

```
- hosts: remote_1
  tasks:
    - name: first file check
      stat:
        path: /root/abc.txt
        #get_checksum: yes
        checksum_algorithm: sha256
      register: test_file_check_1

    - debug:
        var: test_file_check_1.stat.checksum
      when: test_file_check_1.stat.exists

- hosts: remote_2
  tasks: 
    - name: next check
      stat:
        path: /root/abc.txt
        #get_checksum: yes
        checksum_algorithm: sha256
      register: test_file_check_2

    - debug: 
        var: test_file_check_2.stat.checksum
      when: test_file_check_2.stat.exists

- name: Block run only if file has no changes
  command: /bin/true
  when: test_file_check_1.stat.checksum != test_file_check_2.stat.checksum
```

Above code gives error for last block.
ERROR! 'when' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/root/two_file_stat.yml': line 27, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Block run only if file has no changes
  ^ here

Answer (score 0):

You Should run against a **host** and **tasks** . In the last part you didn't specify any **hosts** and **tasks** part.

```
- name: Block run only if file has no changes
  hosts : localhost
  tasks:
  - command: /bin/true
    when: test_file_check_1.stat.checksum != test_file_check_2.stat.checksum
```